# React-Native IOS, Failed to show the changed external image resource

Tags: react-native

Version：0.17 IOS
Xcode：7.2
I test `<Image>` use external image resource, like

```
<Image style={styles.img} source={{uri:'http://www.xxxx.com/xxxxx/0.jpg'}}></Image>
```

It shows good. But when I change the another image. I open the app, it doesn't show the new image, it still shows the old image.

[update]

Maybe I found some bug.

1. I build project first. `<Image>` shows fine.
2. I change another image in server.
3. I cmd+R in simulator. It will show new image (it's good).
4. I cmd+R again, it shows old image. No matter how I do anything (stop xcode and rebuild). It will show the oldest image, unless I uninstall application and rebuild it anew.

It’s strange.

[image]

404? But it can show the image.

Comment: Do you change the `uri` or do you replace `0.jpg`?

Comment: No,I don't change any code.I just use another image replace 0.jpg in server without rename it.It also show old image resource in simulator and device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue about image caching in React Native: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1397. The cache is never expired.

The suggested solution is to add a random parameter to your image uri, so it won't be cached.

```
uri: 'http://www.xxxx.com/xxxxx/0.jpg?r=' + new Date().getTime()
```

Answer (score 0):

Restart the packager process (Ctrl-C to kill the Terminal process on a Mac)

Comment: It don't work.I found some maybe bug.1.I build project first.<Image> show fine.2.I change another image in server.3.I cmd+R in simulator.it will show new image(it's good).4.I cmd+R again,it show old image.No matter how I do anything(stop xcode and rebuild).It will show the oldest image,unless I uninstall application and rebuild it a new.It‘s strange.Xcode7.2+React Native 0.17.

Comment: Is there a stale main.jsbundle being loaded by your AppDelegate.m?  https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#troubleshooting

Comment: yes.Itry it load from main.jsbundle and localhost.It including this problem.It show this "::1 - - [07/Jan/2016:07:32:31 +0000] "GET /flow/ HTTP/1.1" 404 18 "-" "bb/1 CFNetwork/758.2.8 Darwin/15.2.0"" ,but it can show the image.